# Batch file to delete text when it is a certain date

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file and have no idea where to begin.  I need a batch file that reads the text from a file and compares the date written to todays date, and if they are more then 30 days apart then it would delete that date line with the next line of code.  As in the example below.

> 6/1/15
>   ALbert
>   6/15/15
>   Rodger
>   7/3/15
>   Steve
>   5/6/15
>   BOB

If the day the file was run was 7/5/15 the text file would look like

> 6/15/15
>   Rodger
>   7/3/15
>   Steve

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Date/time math is possible in batch, but it's messy.  Would you consider a vbscript or PowerShell solution?

Comment: As long as it is something that can be made to run automatically any solution would be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Date/time math in batch is possible, but messy, and I recommend a higher-level language for this problem.  Here is some PowerShell that solves your problem.

```
$foundDateToRemove = $false
$date = [datetime]::Now
Get-Content 'input.txt' | foreach {
    if ([datetime]::TryParse($_, [ref]$date)) {
        # Line is a date.  Remove it if it's more than 30 days old
        if ($date.AddDays(30).CompareTo([datetime]::Now) -lt 0) {
            $foundDateToRemove = $true
        }
        else {
            # Date still current; output line
            $_
        }
    }
    elseif ( $foundDateToRemove ) {
        # This is the line after the removed date
        $foundDateToRemove = $false
    }
    else {
        # This is any other line in the file.  Output it for good measure.
        $_
    }
} | Out-File 'output.txt'
```

This script opens a file called `input.txt` and writes to `output.txt`.  If you want overwrite behavior, `copy output.txt input.txt` after running.

Some of your date examples are ambiguous.  For example, "6/1/15" could be January 6 or it could be June first.  The script will parse the date using your computer's local culture format, which in your case I assume is `M/d/yy`.  If you need to refine that format, modify the script to pass a format parameter to [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, depending on the encoding of your file, you may need to pass an `-Encoding` parameter to `Out-File`.  The default is system ANSI.